# Cálculo sempre ativo em JQuery

Tags: jquery, html5

### Preciso do seguinte:

Tenho 3 campos de entrada para valores/moeda.
Esses valores não são preenchidos em sequência, outros campos, com outros valores são preenchidos entre esse 3 campos.
Preciso saber, como eu faço para que o resultado apareça, do cálculo desses 3 campos, **somente** quando os 3 valores forem preenchidos, ou seja, deixar a fórmula sempre "ativa", "ligada", para que a qualquer momento o resultado seja exibido, como uma célula do Excel.
Espero que a pergunta esteja clara.

Comment: Posta seu codigo ai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [.change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) para verificar quando estes campos estão sofrendo alrteração e apenas exibir o resultado em uma `div` ou um `span` quando os 3 possuirem algum valor.

### Exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#one, #two, #three").change(function() {
    if ($("#one").val() != "" && $("#two").val() != "" && $("#three").val() != "") {
        total = parseInt($("#one").val()) + parseInt($("#two").val()) + parseInt($("#three").val());
      $("#resultado").text(total);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#resultado {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="one" placeholder="Campo 1" type="number">
<br>
<input id="two" placeholder="Campo 2" type="number">
<br>
<input id="three" placeholder="Campo 3" type="number">
<br>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Beleza @Erlon Charles, vou tentar

Comment: Em partes deu certo, porém, o resultado apareceu "0", zero. Será que não é por estar convertendo os valores em int, parseInt, sendo que os valores estão em 0,00

Comment: eu não posso criar mais de uma function, como você me sugeriu para calcular outros valores em outras fórmulas?

Comment: Pra pegar casa decimais vc usa parseFloat()

Comment: Dentro do `If` que verifica se há conteúdo nos 3 inputs você pode colocar o que quizer, qualquer cálculo ou função

Answer (score 0):

Assim:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="data_value">
<input type="text" class="data_value">
<input type="text" class="data_value">

<span id="result"></span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.data_value').keyup(function() {
    calc()
});

function calc() {
   var sum = 0;
   $('.data_value').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $("#result").text(sum += +$(this).val())
      }
   });
}
```

[EXEMPLO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jcm7s45h/1/)

Comment: Ele quer que atualiuze APENAS quando os 3 campos estiverem preenchidos

Comment: @Jefferson Alison, é que cada input que tenho, tem um id e no seu exemplo todos são a mesma class.
Como posso ajustar o seu código com os meus ids?

Comment: @GustavoSevero, fiz dessa forma pra ficar dinâmico. Você pode adicionar quantos input quiser. Se está usar o id, pode add o atributo normalmente no input ou você quer que realmente seja com ID?

Comment: @JeffersonAlison, eu costumo usar só id, mas posso usar os dois, juntos, em um input?

Comment: Outra coisa @JeffersonAlison, eu preciso que a entrada dos valores seja com "," e não ".", entende? É pra ser 1,11, por exemplo e não 1.11. E no seu exemplo só funciona se for 1.11. Sim, eu entendo que "," e JS é reconhecido como string, mas  então, preciso converter de "," para ".". Já tentei fazer isso, mas não deu certo.